# Can I create an Electron app with only index.html (and NO other files)?

Tags: node.js, electron

In Electron v20.0.2, it possible to enable `nodeIntegration` (disable `contextIsolation`) and use a `<script>` tag to **embed all business logic within a single `index.html`** (no separate `main.js`, `renderer.js`, or `package.json`)?

I'm looking to embed a preexisting, fully-trusted intranet-only website into a frame with limited user inspectability, but I will need to wrap this interaction with filesystem and process-table access.

Comment: well you need a main.js to create the window. Do you mean no files besides index.html and main.js? So you want to put this site in an iframe in index.html? Do you even need to do that or just load it directly into a `BrowserWindow`? In any case, you'll need some other files (like main.js) to interact with the filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You must have an entrypoint main.js file that initializes the Electron renderer, and a separate index.html file to bootstrap the DOM.